# Изменить количество выдаваемых строк при запросе в PL/SQL Developer

Tags: plsql-developer

Предположим, у меня таблица из 1000 записей.
Делаю:

```
select * from table
```

И получаю в результатах только 25 записей.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какую настройку необходимо изменить, чтобы получить все записи в результате?

Comment: Не пользовался PL/SQL Developer, но [здесь](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/151651/) советуют зайти в настройки `Preferences -> Window Types -> SQL Window -> Records per page`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы изменить количество записей на странице, нужно зайти в настройки:

`Preferences` > `Window Types` > `SQL Window` > `Records per page`

Будьте аккуратны, возможно "подвисание" программы при выгрузке большого объема данных.